# c++ pointer to array of strings

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, malloc

Have a look at this code: I am trying to read in a number of strings from the console and store them in a dynamic array.

```
int Doctor::addPatients()
{
  string* names = NULL;
  int num;
  cout << "how many patients are to be added? ";
  cin >> num;
  numPatients=num;
  names = new string[numPatients];
  for(int i=0;i++;i<numPatients){
    cout << "enter the next patient's name: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin >> names[i];
  }
  patients = names; //patients is a private member variable of class Doctor
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x10c100898: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Stop using pointers, change to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i++;i<numPatients)  // Condition is the second expression in for syntax
```

Wrong syntax.

```
for(int i=0;i<numPatients; i++)
```

What compiler are you using ? You should get a compilation error than a run-time error. Also did you write a copy constructor ? For more info see [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). To ease the job, use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Man I really messed up that for loop. Thank you. One of those things I didn't even think about looking at again (after fixing the first problem). I'm using g++ on Mac OSX, Xcode 4.4.1, no flags except for -g when debugging.

Answer (score 3):

you do not initialize the integer i

Comment: For example: std::shared_ptr<std::string> s(new std::string());

Comment: Using shared pointers sounds like a good idea. That said, I'd still like to know the problem with the code as written.

Answer (score 1):

In the for statement, `for(int i;i++;i<numPatients)`

`i` should be initialised to 0 and condition should be the second parameter
Correct format should be -

```
for(int i=0;i<numPatients;i++)
```

`cin` is not good method to get the string input. cin reads only till it sees space character (space,newline,tab..) Alternatively use getline function -

syntax:

```
getline(cin,names[i])
```

Comment: Formatting wasn't good enough and stripped out the explanation.